# How to disable validation of Host info on request header in spring boot app

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot

I have a vendor application sending Host=servername:8444s on their header - note-port is ending with character **s**. and it looks like it causes an issue and the request cannot be passed to dispatcherServlet.

I have detailed logs on below post.
[what would be the reason not detecting RestController for some requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58312298/what-would-be-the-reason-not-detecting-restcontroller-for-some-requests)

Is there a way to disable validation of Header info(hostname:port) in spring boot application?

Please, guide me.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat (not Spring Boot) is returning a 400 as the host header is invalid, there is no configuration option to change this behaviour.

A quote from https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html

> **14.23 Host**
>
> The Host request-header field specifies the Internet host and port
>   number of the resource being requested, as obtained from the original
>   URI given by the user or referring resource (generally an HTTP URL, as described in section 3.2.2). The Host field value MUST represent
>   the naming authority of the origin server or gateway given by the
>   original URL. This allows the origin server or gateway to
>   differentiate between internally-ambiguous URLs, such as the root "/"
>   URL of a server for multiple host names on a single IP address.
>
> ```
>    Host = "Host" ":" host [ ":" port ] ; Section 3.2.2
> ```
>
> A "host" without any trailing port information implies the default
>   port for the service requested (e.g., "80" for an HTTP URL). For
>   example, a request on the origin server for
>   http://www.w3.org/pub/WWW/ would properly include:
>
> ```
>    GET /pub/WWW/ HTTP/1.1
>    Host: www.w3.org
> ```
>
> A client MUST include a Host header field in all HTTP/1.1 request
>   messages . If the requested URI does not include an Internet host name
>   for the service being requested, then the Host header field MUST be
>   given with an empty value. An HTTP/1.1 proxy MUST ensure that any
>   request message it forwards does contain an appropriate Host header
>   field that identifies the service being requested by the proxy. All
>   Internet-based HTTP/1.1 servers **MUST respond with a 400 (Bad Request)**
>   status code to any HTTP/1.1 request message which lacks a Host header
>   field.